# Auto align elements in table

Tags: algorithm, sorting, matrix

I need to make an algorithm which will align elements in table by using smallest possible number of rows.

Elements that need to bee sorted should keep the horizontal position/alignment

Like this:
[[image]

I hope someone already did this.
Thanks!

Comment: Where did the blue stripe 14 come from? It's absent in 'input data'.

Comment: @fail, removed by mistake, will fix in sec

Comment: This looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem to me

Comment: Your example shows ALL coloured stripes preserving their horizontal positions, moved only vertically. This is so special that it's hardly a pure coincidence, rather seems a requirement. If so, please specify it explicitly; otherwise show example with at least some stripes breaking the apparent rule, that is moved horizontally (say, shift the red 12 stripe several cells to the right in the 'input' sheet).

Comment: @CiaPan You are right, this is just an example. I just need an algorithm to position elements to the top using with leaving less free space.

Comment: @Luka, this is what those HDD defragmentation programs do (or used to do back in the time when people bothered with stuff like that). Googling for that might give you some hints. Though I never saw one which was not obviously totally stupid (moving stuff around in a trial-and-error fashion). ;)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: I assume that you mean that each item must fit on one row, and one row only (it cannot break up into the next row), but that they can move horizontally.

Heuristically/naively, I would do it like this:

- Sort the elements by length.
- Try to fill the first free row by naively picking (from longest to shortest) items until the row is full or no more matching elements can be found.
- Repeat until all elements are done.

This will finish (relatively) quickly (somewhere between O(nlogn) and O(n^2) depending on heuristic "shortcuts") but leave more holes than necessary and turn up otherwise non-optimal solutions.

I'd wager this problem is equivalent to one of the classical NP-complete problems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems , so you likely will not find a good practical non-heuristic solution.